# I have trading restriction on my company stock. Can I trade correlated ones?

Tags: finance, insider-trading

I work for a company that is listed on the Nasdaq. Each quarter, employees have trading restrictions six weeks before the company results are released and two days after the release to avoid insider trading.

Is it considered *insider trading* to trade a correlated stock during that restricted period?

Edit as per @George White comment:

> How correlated it is?

Same industry. e.g. I work for Coca-Cola and trade Pepsi stocks.

> Is it insider trading or Is it breaking company rules?

In that case, I'm more interested in Insider Trading.

Comment: If you don’t get a suitable response here, you may wish to consider asking over at MoneySE who have their own [insider-trading](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insider-trading) tag, but you should check first to see if it would be [on-topic](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or not.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I hesitated to select the right SE.

Comment: Can you explain how correlated it is?  Just the same industry or a derivative of the actual stock you can't trade?

Comment: The answer is 100% dependent upon the answer to the clarifying question from @GeorgeWhite

Comment: There was a similar question over on Money.SE [Conflict of trading restrictions with having ETF and mutual funds](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/141195/conflict-of-trading-restrictions-with-having-etf-and-mutual-funds)

Comment: Also you might be unclear  about distinguishing  the two questions - 1. is it insider trading ? and  2. Is it breaking company rules ?

Comment: Adding this one for reference: [Is it insider trading when I already own stock in an ETF and then the ETF adds the company I work for?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/134945/is-it-insider-trading-when-i-already-own-stock-in-an-etf-and-then-the-etf-adds-t?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: So your inside knowledge at Coke will affect the industry when it comes out? Coke is poison so Pepsi goes down also due to consumer confusion (or goes  up because it has the market to itself?) Good question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what those trading restrictions are? how they are worded? what is the source of the information that would prompt you to trade correlated assets? The specific jurisdiction is also relevant.